# Trying to make an autorole discord bot using Discord.py rewrite

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make an bot that as soon as a member joins, automatically gives them a role. This is my code and I can't seem to work out what the problem is. Hopefully someone more smart and experienced can help me

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    role = get(member.guild.roles, name = ROLE)
    await member.add_roles(role)
    print(f'{member} was given {role}')
```

Comment: Are there any errors currently?

Comment: There is no errors but when someone joins the role is not given

Comment: It’s an intent issue

Comment: Do you have a `on_command_error` event? Where did you define the `ROLE`?

Comment: It’s an intent error, member events such as on_member_join will require this turned on

Comment: Yeah, @Cohen is correct, you will need to do `intents = discord.Intents.default()` and `intents.members = True` or something similar to get this working

Comment: I do not have an on_command_error event and I defined my role at the start of my code after I imported everything

Comment: Okay where would I put the intents command?

Comment: At the top of your code, add intents=intents after your bot prefix like included in the answer below

Answer (score 2):

As the event is not producing any errors, it most likely means it’s an issue with member intents.

Any events to do with members will require these intents to be enabled from the Discord developer portal and defined in your code. Your code is looking fine and should work, until you have enabled intents. Intents can be enabled from the bot page and should be off by default, for member intents, turn it on.

They can be defined within code after you have enabled in the portal:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=',', intents=intents)
```

Comment: If it worked then you should mark it as correct